# Thousands of goldfish are living in the West Medical Lake in large numbers, _[?]_ they are crowding out the native fish population. Fill in the blank

Tags: sentence

Thousands of goldfish are living in the West Medical Lake in large numbers, ______ they are crowding out the native fish population.

Is the word "and" correct for the blank? Why or why not? The answer is "where", but I think "and" is correct. Please explain.

Comment: Your question isn't suitable for the site, as it isn't on a point of learning English. You could research "where" clauses quite easily. As it stands, you just want us to prove your teacher wrong (they aren't - also research why you shouldn't place 'and' after a comma).

Comment: _Populwhere_ isn't a word; you have made a typing error. It's a bad sentence anyway, because it's unnecessary to include both _Thousands of_ and _in large numbers_. "...in West Medical Lake, where..." would make better sense. "And" is possible too.

Answer (score 1):

The original sentence:

> Thousands of goldfish are living in the West Medical Lake in large
> numbers, ______ they are crowding out the native fish population.

"And" going in the blank is indeed correct English. (Even though the sentence could be improved, and it is borderline incorrect even with the right answer; see Kate's comment.) However, if there are multiple options such as on an assignment, it may not be the correct or best *answer*.

First, let's realize that "where" serves to connect the two clauses and is grammatically correct. If both are correct, why is "where" better? Here is a rule of thumb that might be useful in similar situations: when you can connect clauses with multiple grammatically correct words, the best word is the one that is most specific (conveys the most information, or conveys information more clearly), and is the one that reduces the number of independant clauses. When we choose "where" over "and," it does both of these.

1. Using "and" could mean that goldfish are living in the lake, and also, separately, they are crowding out the native fish population, perhaps in a different location. Now, most people would assume that this probably refers to the same location, but we can be more clear and explicit by using "where." When we use "where," we are saying that not only are the fish living in the lake very numerous, and not only are they crowing out the native fish population, but they are crowing out the native fish population *in the same lake* that they are described to be numerous in.
2. Independant clauses joined by a conjunction, especially "and," are sometimes not the best way to connect ideas together. You are simply stating one thing then another thing. You could use a period. You get no additional information with "and" above what you would get using a period. The end result is basically two sentences. When more advanced writers write, they often use more complex connecting words. These flow better when the sentence isn't broken up by "and" into two distinct parts that can be read on their own.

Watch this:

> Thousands of goldfish are living in the West Medical Lake in large numbers

[We can start and stop reading and be satisfied.]

> they are crowding out the native fish population.

[We can start and stop reading and be satisfied.]

> Thousands of goldfish are living in the West Medical Lake in large numbers where

[What? What comes after where! We want to read more of this to understand what it's saying, as we clearly haven't finished yet.]

This idea of forcing the reader to connect ideas by using a connecting word that doesn't form more independant clauses can be useful.

Comment: Either _thousands of_ or _in large numbers_ should be omitted.